# How make jQuery pinned/grid layout?

Tags: jquery, layout, grid

I need make layout that must look exactly like below 2 sites. How should I do it?

http://pinterest.com/
http://hakim.se/

Comment: As the about page say, "Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site". What's the point to ask non-programming question, without any research? For that specific case, Google is your friend ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [jQuery plugin Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For grid layouts I would suggest 960.css

- http://960.gs/

It's the most common way to create grid layouts nowadays. Otherwise you could also use the grid system of Twitter Bootstrap:

- http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html

Comment: Thanks for you comment. But its not about grid. If you look http://pinterest.com/ careful, you can see all floated blocks positioned like chain.

Comment: You still not understand my idea. I think its because of my poor English, I can't describe it good. On http://pinterest.com/ all blocks shifted up. For example after 1st row finished, 2nd rows blocks starts right after 1st row block elements end. Not whole new row.

Comment: I mean what have you tried so far ? what is your code ? you should consider a grid layout and float your div's within them thats the magic that should be done.

Comment: @Gerelt Od: Maybe you need to add another example -> http://hakim.se/ <- in your post -- i'm not sure if any jquery plugin available for that, but web is naturally open-source, view the source code! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are looking for the jQuery "Masonry" plugin http://masonry.desandro.com/

You had mentioned how blocks shift. That's what this script does. If you want to see it in action, you should check out the [animation example](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/animating-jquery.html). Resize your browser to see the effect.